# Automatically input a password when a bash script is run

Tags: bash, passwords, sudo

For example, say if I have a script saying:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

How do I put the root password into the script so that it accepts it as the password when it reads and executes the sudo line (so I don't have to type it manually)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Spawning an [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) session within your bash script is typically how you automate interactive prompts.

e.g.

```
expect -c "
spawn sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
expect -nocase \"password:\" {send \"$PASS\r\"; interact}
"
```

Note that this isn't the recommended approach in this case as it is a **huge** security hole to store your root password in a bash script.

The correct solution would be to edit your `/etc/sudoers/` to not prompt you for a password for that binary.

```
#in /etc/sudoers
neohexane ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/setpci
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the `/etc/sudoers/` approach. That would be my reccomendation.

Comment: "isn't recommended" seems like an understatement. I'd remove the expect solution altogether. Unless this is his own personal box, he should absolutely not be leaving the root password lying around in a plain text file.

Comment: I think it's worth keeping as an example of how to use expect. I'll emphasise how not recommended it is.

Comment: @cmh : Will this work for linux ..If no, then please give me a solution

Comment: Leaving the password "Lying around" is the real problem with security.  You can not automate a system unless the automatic has the password, and giving that password securely is a major pain.  Even using the best method given... (using "--login-path"), is technically not real secure as the password is still there, just encrypted.  Without more information what is to say a hacker that gets on the system can extract the password from the ".mylogin.cnf" file?  Still it that is the most secure method so far.