# How to input password for "su -" from a Unix script and have it store in the history?

Tags: java, bash

I am currently working on a java application to get "su -" access to a Linux host. I already know the password, but I want to be able to execute the "su -" command from a bash script and have the command saved to the history. I know that it is bad practice and a security risk, but it is apart of the design of my application. I have tried many variations though, and although people have said they work, I have yet to find one that works.

**Tried actions:**

- `echo "password" | su -`
- `su <user> -p <password>`
- `sudo -S su`

I have tried many more but non of them seem to work. All help is appreciated. Thanks
P.S I am using the JSCH library, so I am also looking into that as a possible answer.

Comment: "I know that it is a bad practice and a security risk, but it is a part of the design of my application" -- have you asked a separate question about how to avoid that design?

Comment: Hello Charles, Yes I have. Though like I said prior, for my application to work I need the password to print to the history.

Comment: Could you link to that question?

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't read your comment thoroughly. No I did not ask a question about how to avoid the design.

Comment: If you _really_ need to do this, the classic way to do it is to use [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).  See [Trouble logging in user using su and expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29174337/4154375) for example code.  Another better option (almost all other options are better) may be to use passwordless sudo.  See [How to setup passwordless `sudo` on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/160581/476049).

Comment: See [Automatically input a password when a bash script is run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10606958/4154375) and [How to provide password to a command that prompts for one in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4857702/4154375).